# How to show all data elements using D3 and Bootstrap?

Tags: d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just started with D3 and my HTML below is supposed to show vertical bars as per array (5 bars) but instead it only shows 3 bars.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.bar {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 75px;
            background-color: teal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">D3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

    d3.select("body")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "bar");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I move `<script>...</script>` before `nav`, I could see correct number of bars (5).  For performance reasons I would like to maintain my original order and yet get it resolved.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current implementation, when you call `selectAll("div")`, the resulting selection contains the two `<div>` elements already present in the DOM (class `container` and class `navbar-header`). The first two data values (5 and 10) are associated with those two `<div>` elements. The remaining three data values (15, 20, and 25) are the only values in the `enter()` selection.

An easy fix would be to use `selectAll("div.bar")` instead, though you might want to re-read the D3.js documentation to better understand exactly why your original code is wrong.

Comment: Aha. You nailed it.  Works great.